# Why is visual studio downloading pdb files into my source location?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, pdb-files

When I open a C# project in visual studio 2012 update 1, visual studio immediately fills my source directory with pdb directories. I assume these have to do with downloading the symbols for the framework, a feature I've always had enabled, but only recently did the sources get put in my solution directory. How do I put these back in their default location? (I've attached a screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the normal place? `Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols > Cache Symbols in this directory`

Comment: Yeah -> My Cache Symbol directory is still the default "\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache"

Comment: I doubt this will help but the Environmental variable `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` isn't set to put symbols in your solution directory?

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558829(v=vs.85).aspx my value for `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` should work fine: `cache*%LOCALAPPDATA%\SymbolCache;srv*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` but it doesn't appear to. :(  That directory does exist, and PDB file do get downloaded there, but they also get copied to the solution directory. :(

Comment: Thanks for the working example of `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` - this solved an opposite problem, that symbols were not cached.